# ZeroMQ Pub/Sub simplest example is not working - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

Following the [example in zmq documentation](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html), here is my take with minor changes.

#### publisher.py

```
import zmq
import random
import time

port = "5556"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)


while True:
    topic = random.randrange(9999,10005)
    messagedata = random.randrange(1,215) - 80
    print "%d %d" % (topic, messagedata)
    socket.send("%d %d" % (topic, messagedata))
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### subscriber.py

```
import sys
import zmq

port = "5556"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)


while True:
    print socket.recv()
```

I then execute them from terminal, and while publisher is publishing (i.e. printing outs the lines), subscriber never gets out of `socket.recv()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

adding

```
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
```

to subscriber, did the trick!

here is the updated subscriber.py

```
import sys
import zmq

port = "5556"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)

while True:
    print socket.recv()
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept your answer so others will know you're all set.

Comment: @Jason I will when I can (currently states: "You cannot accept your own answer in 21 hours")

Comment: Fair enough, I had forgotten how long it makes you wait to accept your own answer.

Comment: This fix worked for me, but note that in python 3 you will get a `TypeError: unicode not allowed, use setsockopt_string`, but you can fix this by calling `socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")` (note the `b""` in the second argument to send a plain byte string)

Comment: pub/sub is all about topic filter. Removing it is not solution.